# Azure Container Registry unable to resolve Private Endpoints connected in same VNET

Tags: networking, azure-virtual-network

I have an Azure Container Instance in my VNET. However, from the ACI I am trying to resolve my Azure Storage Account which is enabled with Private Endpoints in the same VNET but not able to resolve. What could be the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by resolve here? Can you please elloborate more what you exact trying to do?

Comment: My Storage Account is Enabled with Private Endpoints.. So from the Container Instance when I try to do `nslookup private-endpoint-address-of-my-storage-account` it is getting resolved to Public IP Address and not Private IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this command to get the Private IP address of Private endpoint of storage account.**

```
nslookup <storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net
```

Replace <**storage-account-name**> with the name of the storage.

**Note : I have configure the privaate endpoint while creating the storage account itself.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

A private IP address of 10.0.0.5 is returned for the storage account name. This address is in the subnet of the virtual network you created previously.

***Refernce : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-storage-portal#test-connectivity-to-private-endpoint***